# How to get Account Id in VF page to controller

Tags: visualforce, community

Hi I sent my entire code

**VF Page: DEMO**

```
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:commandButton value="Call visualforce Page" action="{!click}"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
```

**Controller:NewAndExistingController**

```
public class NewAndExistingController {
    Account acc = NEW Account();    public PageReference click() { 
       PageReference openvfpage = New Pagereference('/apex'+'/XYZ');    
       openvfpage.setRedirect(false);
       return openvfpage ;         
    }   
    public NewAndExistingController() {    }  
}
```

**VF Page:XYZ**

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="MyOrderPadController" >
    <apex:detail />
        <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >     
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>          
    <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>                   
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>                               
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Order Pad">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Order_Description__c}"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Creat_Date__c}"  />
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Closed_Date__c}"  />
                     <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Conformation__c}"  />  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:MyOrderPadController**

```
public class MyOrderPadController { 
   public Order__c order{ get; private set;
}  
      public MyOrderPadController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {     
   order = (Order__c)sc.getRecord();     
  }    
public PageReference save()      {       
    order.Account__c = '0019000000NAracffo';//for testing only                
            IF(order.Conformation__c == TRUE){
                                          INSERT order;               
      PageReference newpage = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());                    newpage.setRedirect(true);              
      return newpage;                        
}                                     
                   return null;          
}
```

Here **DEMO** VF page attached the Account Object under the one section.Please see the screen short [image]

When ever user click the "**Call visualforce Page"** button then go to **XYZ** VF page,In this page how to get  the current Account Id
and how to pass Account Id to "**MyOrderPadController**".As of now Account id is hard coded, how to get account id?

the above code is working as accepted but I am unable to get the current Account Id only?Please let me  know as soon as possible......

Best Regards,
Ramesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in here you **click** method:

```
public class NewAndExistingController {
    Account acc = NEW Account();    
    public PageReference click() { 
        PageReference openvfpage = New Pagereference('/apex'+'/XYZ');   
        openvfpage.getParameters().put('account',yourAccountVar);
        openvfpage.setRedirect(false);
        return openvfpage ;         
    }   
    public NewAndExistingController() {    }  
}
```

Then, in the receiving VF page, you would get it through:

```
String var = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('account');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set parameter to the url and get it...

Please refer this link...

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_quick_start_query_params.htm